# Maven: is it necessary to put maven-jar-plugin in POM?

Tags: maven

I found that even without specifying `maven-jar-plugin` in the POM, when I run mvn package, it will still generate the JAR.

So what is the point to include it as a plugin explicitly in the POM file ?

Comment: Usually only to define the version the appropriate plugin via pluginManagement.

Comment: To pin the version of the plugin.  You may have very good reasons for not just accepting the one that your particular verison of Maven uses.  This is typically due to needing a specific feature or to avoid a buggy version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...the version, *or* custom configuration/execution, the "default configuration" in Maven:3.8.4 is:

```xml
 ...
   <build>
     <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- in maven#plugins we "never" need to write <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> , since this is also "default plugin group id" -->
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.8.4:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
        <version>2.4</version>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.8.4:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.8.4:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
            <phase>package</phase>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.8.4:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.8.4:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
```

You can "always" find your "implicit" configuration(s) by issuing:

```bash
mvn -Doutput=eff.pom.xml -Dverbose=true help:effective-pom -P myProfile,...
```

...and inspection of `eff.pom.xml`. [Ref](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) (or use [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans)' "effective pom" view/tab;)

Comment: and the 2.4 is an "old darling"... (comparing to current: 3.2.1)... so setting the version explicitly *can have* "effects"! I guess this big gap (between maven core and default plugin versions) is due to some "compatibility requirements". For "green field", i'd recommend to use the latest (plugin versions)!